# Excel function that converts "DD/MM/YY HH:MM" from text to a date value?

Tags: excel

I'm using this for forecasting. I have found out how to convert date and time alone, but nothing for the format I'm presented with...

Comment: The answer will depend on your local settings.  Do you use `dd/mm/yyyy` or `mm/dd/yyyy` in you local settings?

Comment: [Select a blank cell, suppose Cell C2, and type this formula =(C2-DATE(1970,1,1))*86400](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2473-excel-timestamp-to-date.html)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the text string is in cell A1, you can use the following formula:

```
=DATE(2000+MID(A1,7,2), MID(A1,4,2), LEFT(A1,2)) + TIME(MID(A1,10,2), MID(A1,13,2), 0)
```

Note that this will fail for dates with a year starting with 19XX which is due to your input only having the two-character year.

Comment: This is outputting the date, however it isn't including the time of day

Comment: I believe what you're seeing is the default Excel `Date` format, which doesn't include the time. You can change the format by right-clicking -> Number Format -> Time -> and select a format that includes the time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following for input data in text format in cell `A1`:

```
=LET(d,1*TEXTSPLIT(A1,{"/"," "}),DATE(2000+INDEX(d,3),INDEX(d,2),INDEX(d,1))
 +INDEX(d,4))
```

It returns the input value in date & time format, then you can represent it in the format you consider as follows:
[image: output]

We use `TEXTSPLIT` to extract each element of the string, then use it build the date via `DATE` function. The `TEXTSPLIT` output was converted as numeric, so `INDEX(d,4)` represents the time as a decimal number, then we can add to the `DATE` output to include the time portion of it.

Another way to do it using `DATEVALUE`, but you need to put the text input of this function in the proper format and order according to your system date and time settings. Check this link: [How to correct a #VALUE! error in the DATEVALUE function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-to-correct-a-value-error-in-the-datevalue-function-d17c72f0-8829-482f-a334-14c4f124876e).

In my case is `MM/DD/YYYY`, so I need to put first Month, then the Day, and finally the Year (`{2,3,1}`). If you have the same settings as the input: `DD/MM/YYYY`, then you can remove the call to `TEXTJOIN` function and use directly as input of `DATEVALUE` the output of `INDEX(d,1)`:

```
=LET(d, TEXTSPLIT(A1," "),DATEVALUE(TEXTJOIN("/",,
 INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(INDEX(d,1),"/"), {2,1,3}))) + INDEX(d,,2))
```

The first formula, doesn't depend on your system settings, the second one may be adjusted depending on your system settings and the format of the input data.